# How to configure Redirect URI for Microsoft Application portal for Microsoft teams app

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have created a SharePoint Webpart and launched it to Microsoft Teams.

The webpart needs to send a request to Microsoft Graph for authentication. During development, I added a redirect URL in `apps.dev.microsoft.com` that pointed to my local machine (`https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html`). The authentication worked fine.

When the webpart is located in Teams the URL is channel/tab specific and I can't seem to reproduce the URL in order to finish the authentication.

I have already tried a combination of URLs, hoping they would suffice in the authentication. Here you can see the development Url which does work fine.

[image: App registration portal]

Here is the Webpart with its URL but I cannot find a reference to what each of these Ids mean in order to reproduce the link. Microsoft app registration also does not allow copy & paste of this link as it contains queries.

`https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/tab::d7cdb44e-ed6e-4dwb-82db-b933adc8152d/General?threadId=15:512c0d9b1af125d68b5d310de6f76f@thread.skype&ctx=channel`

Following this link manually takes me to my web-part located in teams but it has query strings which cannot be used in the app reg portal. I have also tried to minify that Url and paste the shortened link - but to no avail.

If anyone can point me in the right direction of re-creating the link I have posted above in the right context or knows of a reason It doesn't work, let me know. Thanks. (Links for demonstration purposes).

Expected results - Sign in window closes and the user is authenticated.

Actual results - Correlation failure for authentication as redirect link does not match.

[image: Correlation failure]

My Webpart has a button - its first function is to authenticate the user with the code below:

```
 public async login(){
  var that = this;
   await me.userAgentApplication.loginPopup(config.scopes).then(async function (idToken) {
    await me.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenPopup(config.scopes).then(async function (accessToken) {
       that.getWebUrl(accessToken);
      }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
    });
}
```

So it uses Microsoft-graph to then do the authentication. I have added the hosted site to the Redirect-Urls list also. This authenticates fine from the sharepoint site - but how else do I send that access token to teams.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI should be pointing to *your* site, not the client application. In other words, you should be redirecting them to a page *you* are hosting. Once that page is called, you process the authentication (convert the authorization code to an access token, store the refresh token, validate the `state` property, etc.) and then redirect them to the final destination.

If you need to pass the final destination through to your page (i.e. retain the link to the channel), you should encode it and pass it using the `state` parameter. This `state` will be returned to the redirection page unaltered. Your app can then decode it to determine the final destination.

Comment: Thanks for the response Marc. I'm still unsure about what you mean. Do you mean manually redirect them to the hosted site & back to teams with the token as opposed to using graph authentication?

Comment: I think you may be combining bits from multiple stacks. What documentation are you following for this?

Comment: I've used '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client' to retrieve data & Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL.js) for authentication - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/README.md.

Comment: Did you define a `tokenReceivedCallback` function when you set up your `userAgentApplication `?

Comment: No I had left it null Marc -  this.userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication(config.appId, null, null); - You think that could be the cause? I see this in the Configuration options "redirectUri(Optional): The redirect URI of your app, where authentication responses can be sent and received by your app. It must exactly match one of the redirect URIs you registered in the portal, except that it must be URL encoded. Defaults to window.location.href." But then I'm back to square one with the url in portal.

Comment: You need to proced a callback to process the result so MSAL knows how to wire it up properly. You may also want to look at how Teams handles authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication